# Cassandra order by a mathematical expression

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a column family with following specifications:

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY places (
  name text,    
  category text,
  latitude double,
  longitude double,
PRIMARY KEY (name, category));
```

What I need, is to search the places and order by distance formula on the basis of latitude and longitudes that is I will provide a set of latitude and longitudes and get results sorted by the shortest distance from those points. This is the query I want to run:

```
SELECT name, distance(latitude, longitude, 37.8074907, -122.4074504) as distance FROM places ORDER BY distance;
```

I have written a UDF named distance that can calculate the distance between two sets of latitudes and longitudes. Now I know that Cassandra does not allow order by a non-clustering key but there is no way I can save all the distances and then cluster them.

I am new to Cassandra so if there is any way to change the design of the table somehow or do something with CQL I am open to it.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, sorting in Cassandra is based on clustering key; that is, order is part of the definition of the table. Your ordering of SELECT results must follow the table design.

Your best bet is to load the SELECT results into memory and sort the data in memory on-demand. (Without more specific information on when and how often you do this operation, it's impossible to give better advice.)

Comment: Firstly, that query is the backbone of my application and secondly, I have like more than 10M places so it's not possible to sort all these records in memory. I need to show the places in the form of pages.

Comment: Ah, some specifics! Is this set of 10M places mostly static (i.e. well-defined and unchanging)? If so, then I could imagine a totally different data model, where the key involves one place and maybe a distance range (e.g. 0 to 50 miles), and the data in that partition(s) lists all 9.99M other places sorted by distance.

Comment: I'm just thinking off the cuff. No guarantees. Cassandra queries are, for the most part, really simple. So I think your problem is more about how to organize your data in Cassandra rather than how to write a sorted-distance query.

Comment: Some further thinking... If this distance query is "the backbone" of your application, consider caching the 10M places in memory. For performance, you do not want to hit *any* datatabase if your application is regularly needing to do some computation on all of the data. On the other hand,  if there is some restriction of your app, a database might help. e.g. if the locations are spread across the globe, but you only query locations by nation-state, you can partition the 10M locations by nation-state.

Comment: Hello, cassandra seems not fit your need. Maybe an another db can helps you like elasticsearch, mongodb or redis for exemple. These db can query geospatial data.